# access two camera simultaneously on raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi4

I am working on a project on raspberry pi 4 OS (64bit), I created two modules one for object detection and the other for face recognition each one access a different USB cams with index 0 and 2, and I run the two modules together using multiprocessing, but the cams do not work simultaneously all the time, one may work and the other gives me can't open camera by index.

so I tried simple code to test the two of them.

```
import time

cam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
time.sleep(2.0)
while True:
    ret1, frame1 = cam1.read()
    ret2, frame2 = cam2.read()


    if ret1:
        frame1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('cam1', frame1)

    if ret2:
        frame2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('cam2', frame2)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
        break

cam1.release()
cam2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but again the same problem they may work or not, or one found and the other not.

i tried to specify the video backend, nothing happen

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(index, cv2.CAP_V4L)
```

i Checked if a USB Webcam is Compatible with Raspberry Pi, and i find the two usb cams

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 10c4:8108 Silicon Labs USB OPTICAL MOUSE
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2a7a:9a18 CASUE CASUE USB Keyboard
    Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0ac8:0345 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. USB 2.0 PC Camera
    Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0c45:6366 Microdia Webcam Vitade AF
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and they appered at the `/dev` directory.

would there be another way two access the two cams ?

Comment: how do you know that the indexes are 0 and 2? have you tried 0 and 1?

Comment: I have tried indexes (0,1), (0,-1),(0,2). and 0,2 indexes only worked most of the time.

Comment: try this fswebcam --device /dev/video0 image.jpg  fswebcam --device /dev/video1 image.jpg

Comment: check this:  ls /dev/

Comment: raspberry pi use even indexes 2,4,6 for each cam, as I saw in different tutorials

Comment: /dev/video0 and /dev/video1 and ls /dev/video*

Comment: @toyotaSupra 
fswebcam --device /dev/video0 image.jpg fswebcam --device /dev/video1 image.jpg  it did not work with video1 but with video2 as i mentioned before it is works with index 0 and 2, but it give me that error                                                                           --- Opening /dev/video2...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video2 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
it can open video2 but no input from it

Comment: if both cameras are on the same USB hub, that can cause trouble. **without using opencv**, try to open both cameras in vlc or guvcview or whatever. until *that* works, it's *not* an opencv problem.